# Kubernetes: list all pods and its nodes

Tags: kubernetes

I have 3 nodes, running all kinds of pods. I would like to have a list of nodes and pods, for an example:

```
NODE1 POD1
NODE1 POD2
NODE2 POD3
NODE3 POD4
```

How can this please be achieved?

Comment: `kubectl get pod --all-namespaces -o json | jq '.items[] | .spec.nodeName + " " + .metadata.name'`

Answer (score 285, accepted):

You can do that with [custom columns](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/overview/#custom-columns):

```
kubectl get pod -o=custom-columns=NAME:.metadata.name,STATUS:.status.phase,NODE:.spec.nodeName --all-namespaces
```

or just:

```
kubectl get pod -o=custom-columns=NODE:.spec.nodeName,NAME:.metadata.name --all-namespaces
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was looking for. It worked, but needed to add --all-namespaces to the command so pods would appear. E.g.: `kubectl get pod --all-namespaces -o=custom-columns=NAME:.metadata.name,STATUS:.status.phase,NODE:.spec.nodeName`

Comment: I found it helpful to add `| sort` at the end of the second command so that the results are grouped by node.

Comment: This is excellent answer to find and group pods by nodes . Helpful in finding which nodes contain which pods

Comment: the -o=wide option will default show you the node as well. ```kubectl get pods -o=wide```

Comment: `| sort -r ` keeps headers at the top of sorting

Comment: @Cirelli94 `| sort -r` only keeps the header at the top if your node names come before NAME alphabetically! (sort -r just reverses the sort order). You would have to use something like `| (read -r; printf "%s\n" "$REPLY"; sort)` to always keep the header at the top (or others from [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11856/sort-but-keep-header-line-at-the-top)).

Answer (score 204):

`kubectl` has a simple yet useful extended output format that you can use like

```
kubectl get pod -o wide
```

so while custom formats provided in other answers are good, this might be a handy shortcut.

Comment: This is so much more straightforward than the rest of the answers.

Comment: The complete command would be `kubectl get pod --all-namespaces -o wide`, this will give all the details including node information. To list down pods for a particular namespace `kubectl get pod -n YOUR_NAMESPACE -o wide`. Hope this helps.

Comment: made my life easy

Answer (score 16):

You can use `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces` to list all the pods from all namespaces and `kubectl get nodes` for listing all nodes.

Comment: OK, thanks. While your commands work, and it was kind of what I was using so far, the goal is to have a single command that outputs the pods/nodes relation. Hope you can please help. Again, thanks!

Comment: Maybe this one helps you: kubectl get pods -o wide, but it will print a lot of infos.

Answer (score 10):

The following command does more or less what you wanted. However, it's more of a `jq` trick than `kubectl` trick:

`kubectl get pod --all-namespaces -o json | jq '.items[] | .spec.nodeName + " " + .status.podIP'`

Comment: Thanks! After installing "jq", unfortunately I get a "parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 10" with your command above.

Comment: This only gives nodes' names & pods' IPs

Comment: @AmineZaine replace the .status.podip with `kubectl get pod --all-namespaces -o json | jq '.items[] | .spec.nodeName + " " + .metadata.name'`

Answer (score 9):

Maybe the answers are a little bit old, now you can simply launch this:

```
kubectl get pods -o wide
```

Answer (score 8):

This gets you:  "nodeName namespace pod"   across the cluster:

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces --output 'jsonpath={range .items[*]}{.spec.nodeName}{" "}{.metadata.namespace}{" "}{.metadata.name}{"\n"}{end}'
```

Answer (score 6):

Not exactly as you wanted cause it describe much more, but you can use

`kubectl describe nodes`

it will expose each pod **per node** in the cluster with the following info

> Namespace | Name | CPU Requests  | CPU Limits  | Memory Requests |
>   Memory Limits

Comment: Thanks very much! Do you know please if it is possible to remove all the extra information and maybe present the details in a simplified table, as per the question above? Again, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can check by executing below command to list out all the pods running in specific node

**kubectl get pods -o wide | grep node_name**