# Pod in Kubernetes unstable - Sometimes available, sometimes not (switching worker nodes all the time)

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-pod, nginx-ingress, kubernetes-service

I try to setup pods in Kubernetes but the pods seem highly unstable. But the responses from the pod seem fully random.

This is the output of an Apache pod running in my k3s cluster (1 master, 3 workers).

```
sebastian@kobol:~$ curl -k http://192.168.30.13:30081
<html><body><h1>It works!</h1></body></html>
sebastian@kobol:~$ curl -k http://192.168.30.13:30081
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.30.13 port 30081: No route to host
sebastian@kobol:~$ curl -k http://192.168.30.13:30081
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.30.13 port 30081: No route to host
sebastian@kobol:~$ curl -k http://192.168.30.13:30081
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.30.13 port 30081: No route to host
sebastian@kobol:~$ curl -k http://192.168.30.13:30081
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.30.13 port 30081: No route to host
sebastian@kobol:~$ curl -k http://192.168.30.13:30081
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.30.13 port 30081: No route to host
sebastian@kobol:~$ curl -k http://192.168.30.13:30081
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.30.13 port 30081: No route to host
sebastian@kobol:~$ curl -k http://192.168.30.13:30081
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.30.13 port 30081: No route to host
sebastian@kobol:~$ curl -k http://192.168.30.13:30081
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.30.13 port 30081: No route to host
sebastian@kobol:~$ curl -k http://192.168.30.13:30081
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.30.13 port 30081: No route to host
sebastian@kobol:~$ curl -k http://192.168.30.13:30081
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.30.13 port 30081: No route to host
sebastian@kobol:~$ curl -k http://192.168.30.13:30081
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.30.13 port 30081: No route to host
sebastian@kobol:~$ curl -k http://192.168.30.13:30081
<html><body><h1>It works!</h1></body></html>
sebastian@kobol:~$ curl -k http://192.168.30.13:30081
<html><body><h1>It works!</h1></body></html>
sebastian@kobol:~$ curl -k http://192.168.30.13:30081
<html><body><h1>It works!</h1></body></html>
sebastian@kobol:~$ curl -k http://192.168.30.13:30081
<html><body><h1>It works!</h1></body></html>
sebastian@kobol:~$ curl -k http://192.168.30.13:30081
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.30.13 port 30081: No route to host
sebastian@kobol:~$ curl -k http://192.168.30.13:30081
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.30.13 port 30081: No route to host
sebastian@kobol:~$ curl -k http://192.168.30.13:30081
<html><body><h1>It works!</h1></body></html>
sebastian@kobol:~$ curl -k http://192.168.30.13:30081
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.30.13 port 30081: No route to host
sebastian@kobol:~$ curl -k http://192.168.30.13:30081
<html><body><h1>It works!</h1></body></html>
sebastian@kobol:~$ curl -k http://192.168.30.13:30081
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.30.13 port 30081: No route to host
sebastian@kobol:~$ curl -k http://192.168.30.13:30081
<html><body><h1>It works!</h1></body></html>
sebastian@kobol:~$ curl -k http://192.168.30.13:30081
<html><body><h1>It works!</h1></body></html>
sebastian@kobol:~$ curl -k http://192.168.30.13:30081
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.30.13 port 30081: No route to host
```

The responses come from one of my worker nodes, but the other two worker nodes behave exactly the same. I would expect to have an Apache instance running on each worker node (the deployment config specifies "replicas: 3")

```yaml
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: apache-deployment
  namespace: webservers
  labels:
    app: apache
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: apache
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: apache
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: apache
          image: httpd:2.4
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
```

```yaml
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: apache-svc
  namespace: webservers
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      protocol: TCP
      name: http
      nodePort: 30081
  selector:
    app: apache
```

On top I try to setup an Ingress using [Nginx ingress controller](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/) for this Apache service. But all I get is "404 page not found" all the time.

```yaml
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: webservers-ingress
  namespace: webservers
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx # use the shared ingress-nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    #nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/service-upstream: "true"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: apache.v-kube-cluster.local
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: apache-svc
                port:
                  number: 80
```

Can anyone give me a hint on how I can stabilize my environment?

---

**UPDATE #1:** Some information about my cluster and pods after I deployed applications. The apache- and nginx-pods and services are the interesting ones.

```sh
sudo kubectl --kubeconfig /etc/rancher/k3s/k3s.yaml get nodes

NAME             STATUS   ROLES                  AGE     VERSION
v-k3s-worker-1   Ready    <none>                 13m     v1.21.4+k3s1
v-k3s-worker-3   Ready    <none>                 8m21s   v1.21.4+k3s1
v-k3s-worker-2   Ready    <none>                 10m     v1.21.4+k3s1
v-k3s-master     Ready    control-plane,master   16m     v1.21.4+k3s1


kubectl --kubeconfig /etc/rancher/k3s/k3s.yaml get pod --all-namespaces -o=custom-columns=NAME:.metadata.name,STATUS:.status.phase,NODE:.spec.nodeName

NAME                                         STATUS      NODE
helm-install-traefik-crd-jf848               Succeeded   v-k3s-master
helm-install-traefik-9mhgg                   Succeeded   v-k3s-master
traefik-97b44b794-trz76                      Running     v-k3s-master
local-path-provisioner-5ff76fc89d-h4hlt      Running     v-k3s-master
metrics-server-86cbb8457f-c95bt              Running     v-k3s-master
coredns-7448499f4d-pjg4c                     Running     v-k3s-master
svclb-traefik-jk2vk                          Running     v-k3s-master
svclb-traefik-bnhv9                          Running     v-k3s-worker-1
svclb-traefik-v8wm6                          Running     v-k3s-worker-2
svclb-traefik-qrg4r                          Running     v-k3s-worker-3
ingress-nginx-admission-create-hv6r9         Succeeded   v-k3s-worker-3
ingress-nginx-admission-patch-dltfr          Succeeded   v-k3s-worker-2
dashboard-metrics-scraper-856586f554-rsqnx   Running     v-k3s-worker-3
ingress-nginx-controller-8cf5559f8-5dqb8     Running     v-k3s-worker-1
kubernetes-dashboard-67484c44f6-ztgpc        Running     v-k3s-worker-2
nginx-deployment-757fbf9d6-kzjtg             Running     v-k3s-worker-1
apache-deployment-5df5f65c6f-zwfqc           Running     v-k3s-worker-2
apache-deployment-5df5f65c6f-qbbld           Running     v-k3s-worker-3
nginx-deployment-757fbf9d6-k5rq7             Running     v-k3s-worker-3
nginx-deployment-757fbf9d6-h5kln             Running     v-k3s-master
apache-deployment-5df5f65c6f-p6ckr           Running     v-k3s-worker-2


sudo kubectl --kubeconfig /etc/rancher/k3s/k3s.yaml get services --all-namespaces

NAMESPACE              NAME                                 TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP     PORT(S)                      AGE
default                kubernetes                           ClusterIP      10.43.0.1       <none>          443/TCP                      25m
kube-system            kube-dns                             ClusterIP      10.43.0.10      <none>          53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP       25m
kube-system            metrics-server                       ClusterIP      10.43.121.217   <none>          443/TCP                      25m
kube-system            traefik                              LoadBalancer   10.43.124.27    192.168.30.10   80:30776/TCP,443:32653/TCP   24m
ingress-nginx          ingress-nginx-controller-admission   ClusterIP      10.43.69.180    <none>          443/TCP                      5m31s
ingress-nginx          ingress-nginx-controller             NodePort       10.43.162.128   <none>          80:30953/TCP,443:32458/TCP   5m31s
kubernetes-dashboard   kubernetes-dashboard                 ClusterIP      10.43.89.177    <none>          443/TCP                      5m5s
kubernetes-dashboard   dashboard-metrics-scraper            ClusterIP      10.43.136.108   <none>          8000/TCP                     5m5s
webservers             apache-svc                           NodePort       10.43.46.218    <none>          80:30081/TCP                 4m18s
webservers             nginx-svc                            NodePort       10.43.100.206   <none>          80:30082/TCP                 4m8s


sudo kubectl --kubeconfig /etc/rancher/k3s/k3s.yaml get ingress --all-namespaces

NAMESPACE    NAME                 CLASS    HOSTS                                                    ADDRESS     PORTS   AGE
webservers   webservers-ingress   <none>   apache.v-kube-cluster.local,nginx.v-kube-cluster.local   10.0.2.15   80      4m31s
```

---

**UPDATE #2:** More Information about my cluster directly from my nodes. I removed all lines from the outputs that are not related to my apache pods (too much information affect readability).

Information from  master node

```sh
# Information from  Ingress
user@v-k3s-master:~$ curl localhost:80 
404 page not found
user@v-k3s-master:~$ curl localhost:443
404 page not found

# exec
user@v-k3s-master:~$ kubectl exec --stdin --tty apache-deployment-5df5f65c6f-qqt4t -- /bin/bash
Error from server (NotFound): pods "apache-deployment-5df5f65c6f-qqt4t" not found

user@v-k3s-master:~$ kubectl exec --stdin --tty apache-deployment-5df5f65c6f-hbbp6 -- /bin/bash
Error from server (NotFound): pods "apache-deployment-5df5f65c6f-hbbp6" not found

user@v-k3s-master:~$ kubectl exec --stdin --tty apache-deployment-5df5f65c6f-x96zm -- /bin/bash
Error from server (NotFound): pods "apache-deployment-5df5f65c6f-x96zm" not found

# pods info
user@v-k3s-master:~$ kubectl --kubeconfig /etc/rancher/k3s/k3s.yaml get pods --all-namespaces -o wide
NAMESPACE              NAME                                         READY   STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE   IP          NODE             NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
ingress-nginx          ingress-nginx-admission-create-pz2m9         0/1     Completed   0          19m   10.42.2.3   v-k3s-worker-2   <none>           <none>
ingress-nginx          ingress-nginx-admission-patch-xmhnp          0/1     Completed   0          19m   10.42.3.3   v-k3s-worker-3   <none>           <none>
ingress-nginx          ingress-nginx-controller-8cf5559f8-sqmqz     1/1     Running     0          19m   10.42.1.3   v-k3s-worker-1   <none>           <none>
webservers             apache-deployment-5df5f65c6f-qqt4t           1/1     Running     0          18m   10.42.2.7   v-k3s-worker-2   <none>           <none>
webservers             apache-deployment-5df5f65c6f-hbbp6           1/1     Running     0          18m   10.42.2.6   v-k3s-worker-2   <none>           <none>
webservers             apache-deployment-5df5f65c6f-x96zm           1/1     Running     0          18m   10.42.1.5   v-k3s-worker-1   <none>           <none>

# services info
user@v-k3s-master:~$ kubectl --kubeconfig /etc/rancher/k3s/k3s.yaml get svc apache-svc
Error from server (NotFound): services "apache-svc" not found

# services info
user@v-k3s-master:~$ kubectl --kubeconfig /etc/rancher/k3s/k3s.yaml get services --all-namespaces -o wide
NAMESPACE              NAME                                 TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP     PORT(S)                          AGE   SELECTOR
ingress-nginx          ingress-nginx-controller-admission   ClusterIP      10.43.185.36    <none>          443/TCP                          30m   app.kubernetes.io/component=controller,app.kubernetes.io/instance=ingress-nginx,app.kubernetes.io/name=ingress-nginx
ingress-nginx          ingress-nginx-controller             NodePort       10.43.124.153   <none>          80:31333/TCP,443:30349/TCP       30m   app.kubernetes.io/component=controller,app.kubernetes.io/instance=ingress-nginx,app.kubernetes.io/name=ingress-nginx
webservers             apache-svc                           NodePort       10.43.216.240   <none>          80:30081/TCP                     29m   app=apache
webservers             nginx-svc                            NodePort       10.43.215.23    <none>          80:30082/TCP                     29m   app=nginx
```

Information from  worker-1

```sh
user@v-k3s-worker-1:~$ kubectl exec --stdin --tty apache-deployment-5df5f65c6f-qqt4t -- /bin/bash
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?

user@v-k3s-worker-1:~$ kubectl exec --stdin --tty apache-deployment-5df5f65c6f-hbbp6 -- /bin/bash
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?

user@v-k3s-worker-1:~$ kubectl exec --stdin --tty apache-deployment-5df5f65c6f-x96zm -- /bin/bash
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

Information from  worker-2

```sh
user@v-k3s-worker-2:~$ kubectl exec --stdin --tty apache-deployment-5df5f65c6f-qqt4t -- /bin/bash
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?

user@v-k3s-worker-2:~$ kubectl exec --stdin --tty apache-deployment-5df5f65c6f-hbbp6 -- /bin/bash
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?

user@v-k3s-worker-2:~$ kubectl exec --stdin --tty apache-deployment-5df5f65c6f-x96zm -- /bin/bash
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

Information from  worker-2

```sh
user@v-k3s-worker-3:~$ kubectl exec --stdin --tty apache-deployment-5df5f65c6f-qqt4t -- /bin/bash
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?

user@v-k3s-worker-3:~$ kubectl exec --stdin --tty apache-deployment-5df5f65c6f-hbbp6 -- /bin/bash
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?

user@v-k3s-worker-3:~$ kubectl exec --stdin --tty apache-deployment-5df5f65c6f-x96zm -- /bin/bash
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

Comment: Could you please confirm that pods are running on [different nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48983354/kubernetes-list-all-pods-and-its-nodes/48983984#48983984)? Could you please confirm that all three pods are in `Running` state?

Comment: I updated my original question with the information.

Comment: Thanks, seems like nodes are running properly. Could you please [exec](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/get-shell-running-container/) into each apache pod and run: `curl localhost:80` and check if it is working? Could you check apache pods IP addresses (`kubectl get pods -o wide`) and make sure the IPs matches the IPs used by service "Endpoints:" (`kubectl get svc apache-svc`)?

Comment: I again updated my original post (see UPDATE #2). I'm troubled because I could not exec into any of my apache pods. So far I thought the pods were up and running. Now I'm confused ... You can see my full project at https://gitlab.com/sommerfeld.sebastian/v-kube-cluster/-/tree/feat/k3s (branch feat/k3s is important, master contains an old and invalid setup) ... You can clone the repo and try for yourself if you like. The repository contains docs on how to use my project. Everything is set up in Vagrantboxes using Virtualbox.

Comment: Thanks for more detailed information, for the outputs, let be more clearer: as you got the pods IP addresses (from the commend `kubectl get pods -o wide -n webservers`) please check if those IPs matches the IPs used by service "Endpoints:" (`kubectl get svc apache-svc -n webservers` - I missed namespace in my previous comment, sorry for that!).

Comment: Please also run `kubectl exec` command to each pod from the **master**  not from the workers and add `-n webservers`, then check if `curl localhost:80` command is working (for example  - `kubectl exec --stdin --tty apache-deployment-5df5f65c6f-x96zm -n webservers -- /bin/bash`).

Comment: I SSH-ed into my master node and ran the commands `kubectl exec --stdin --tty apache-deployment-5df5f65c6f-qqt4t -n webservers -- /bin/bash`, `kubectl exec --stdin --tty apache-deployment-5df5f65c6f-hbbp6 -n webservers -- /bin/bash` and `kubectl exec --stdin --tty apache-deployment-5df5f65c6f-x96zm -n webservers -- /bin/bash` ... Still I get `Error from server (NotFound): pods "apache-deployment-5df5f65c6f-x96zm" not found`. The `curl localhost:80` from the master node returend "404 page not found".

Comment: Please check pods names and namespace using command `kubectl --kubeconfig /etc/rancher/k3s/k3s.yaml get pods --all-namespaces -o wide` and use the proper pods names and namespace in `kubectl exec` commands. Please also compare IP addresses which I asked in previous comment. Please run `curl localhost:80` on the pods that you exec into. Let me know if you get any results. Check also [this article](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/kubernetes-basics/explore/explore-intro/).